# How to prevent default browser scrolling an touchmove combined with a throttled function

Tags: javascript, preventdefault, throttling, touchmove

I need to trigger a function when a finger moves on a touch device.
When you touchmove, the default browser scrolling is disabled with `e.preventDefault();` 
See first section on **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8L96maw8/4/)**.

In order to reduce the traffic, this function is only called every half second while you `touchmove` with `_.throttle` from the `underscore` library. However, browser scrolling is not disabled any more. See [second section](http://jsfiddle.net/8L96maw8/4/).

How can I disable browser scrolling on touch devices even if the called function is throttled?

**Section 1**

```
$('#test1').on("touchmove", function (ev) {
    var e = ev.originalEvent;
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#test1').text(e.targetTouches[0].pageX, e.targetTouches[0].pageY);
});
```

**Section 2**

```
$('#test2').on("touchmove", _.throttle(function (ev) {
  var e = ev.originalEvent;
  e.preventDefault();                      // browser still scrolling - why?
  $('#test2').text(e.targetTouches[0].pageX);
},500));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `e.preventDefault()` and add `return false;` to the end of the function. Example:

```
$('#test1').on("touchmove", function (ev) {
    var e = ev.originalEvent;
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#test1').text(e.targetTouches[0].pageX, e.targetTouches[0].pageY);
});


$('#test2').on("touchmove", _.throttle(function (ev) {
  var e = ev.originalEvent;
  $('#test2').text(e.targetTouches[0].pageX);
  return false;
},500));
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8L96maw8/6/)

Comment: @wurstbrotrest No problem. Glad it helped.